# VB.NET Datatable Column Type

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I load a Datatable to a datagrid view by calling the following function:

```
 Public Sub GetData(ByVal selectCommand As String, ByVal bindingSource As BindingSource, ByVal table As DataTable)
    Try
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\adm\Desktop\222.mdb"
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString)
        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        bindingSource.DataSource = table
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And here is the function call:

```
GetData("select * from products where ID=1 or ID=2", bindingSource1, t1)
```

Now, does the data table define the column types as they are from the source database?
Because when I try to add data to a DateTime column, it says that the column is of type integer but in Access I can see that it is a DateTime Column. So do I need to specify each type for each column or it is done automatically?

Comment: Is this a typed dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the type of the column in which you are passing the **date value** make sure that the value is not `int`.If it so then change it to `datetime`

**EDIT**
Go to the properties of your datatable and change the column type to `datetime`